# Need help for apache poi reading xls with XSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need help reading xls files using apache XSSF.

The implementation of XSSF is working fine for "xlsx". Not working for "xls" files.

Here is the code:

```
    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook("fileName");
    XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
```

Any workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI QuickGuide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api)? It shows you how to read and write both XSSF and HSSF files with basically identical code

Comment: Thanks for u r replay. Yes i can do separately for .xml HSSF and for .xlsx XSSF. But is there any way we can achieve both are with Single implementation?

Answer (score 13):

Rather than using XSSF classes directly, you should use the interfaces that are common between both HSSF (.xls) and XSSF (.xlsx). The snippet of code from your question would then become:

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file); // Or InputStream
 Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
 Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
 Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
 System.out.println("Cell A1 is of type " + cell.getCellType());
```

See the [Apache POI QuickGuide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api) for more information and examples

Comment: this does not seem to work with xlsx. Whenever I try to upload an excel file in that format, I get a weird reflection error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. I'm storing my rows that I get from the excel file in a vector, then passing that vector to another function. When I'm inside that function, the vector is always empty with an XLSX file, but it has the correct value with XLS files.

Comment: Also, that link doesn't demonstarte xssf. Only hssf.

Comment: It does - the code there works identically for both HSSF and XSSF, it just depends which kind of workbook you feed in at the top. If you're having problems, ask a new question and post the complete stacktrace#

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath))
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
is.close();
```

This link below seems to have a solution to this problem...Good luck.

http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/InvalidOperationException-Can-t-open-specified-file-td5524067.html